Issues when applying simulation add-ons to downloaded model
When I applied the Fracture feature of an add-on called KABOOM to the downloaded model, I got the following results



I got some weird new fragments like in the image. How do I fix it?
Then I applied a feature called Blast, and the whole blade shatters instead of fragments.

How do I get it to shatter like particles? I have no way to ask the addon creator, so I'm posting a question!
Here's the link of the video https://streamable.com/3nv36o

I'm afraid that we can't help with third-party addons here. This Q&A site can help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons but there are so many other addons around that it's impossible to help with most of them.
